# get different inner html from same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help with how do you get the different innerhtml from the same class into an input text? This is the code. Thanks.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
  var b = document.getElementById("whispering");
  a.innerHTML = b.value;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="myFunction();" class="name" id="username1"> Username 1 </span>
<span onclick="myFunction();" class="name" id="username2"> Username 2 </span>

<input type="text" id="whispering">
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection, not a single element.

Comment: if I change into ID instead of class..

Comment: Now you've got non-unique id's.

Comment: That's what I thought, the IDs are unique because based on the username. < span id="username1" class="name" > username 1 </span>

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
a[2].innerHTML = b.value;
```

Or if you want the specific item clicked, you could do:

**HTML**:

```
<span id="1" class="name">Content</span>
<span id="2" class="name">Content</span>
```

**JS**:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("name");

for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
    spans[i].onclick = function(){
        this.innerHTML = b.value;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: this also stops the use of inline **JS** :)

Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/yn9wauyk/**

Comment: Did you try this? You'll always get the last span updated when you click.

Comment: @Jamiec the first one was just an example of how to get a specified `span` :) I added onto it in the second block

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me. Turn this code into a snippet or jsfiddle it and you'll see it wont work.

Comment: @Jamiec try it now :)

Comment: Hmm it doesn't work.

Comment: @Neof hmm, it should do :/ I'll upload a fiddle for you :)

Comment: Alright, that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Neof done! give it a look :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, so you need to loop through that and set the `innerHTML` of each individual element:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
  var b = document.getElementById("whispering");

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].innerHTML = b.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<span onclick="myFunction();" class="name" id="1"> HAHA1 </span>
<span onclick="myFunction();" class="name" id="2"> Haha2 </span>

<input type="text" id="whispering">
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better to pass a reference to the clicked element into your method - this solves all problems of referencing the correct element by id or by class.

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
   var b = document.getElementById("whispering");
  elem.innerHTML = b.value;
}
```

```html
<span onclick="myFunction(this);"> HAHA1 </span>
<span onclick="myFunction(this);"> Haha2 </span>

<input type="text" id="whispering">
```